# Perform a query with multiple WHERE clauses using SQLite in Android Studio

Tags: android

Hi im very new to Android dev so i have this query that will look into my table and check whether a certain record is existing given the username and password to as of now i have this

```
public user getLOGusr(String uname, String pass)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USRS, new String[]{KEY_ID,KEY_NAME,KEY_E_ADDR,KEY_PASS} , KEY_NAME + "=?", KEY_PASS + "=?",
                    new String[]{String.valueOf(uname), String.valueOf(pass)});

    return somestuff;
}
```

but it is riddled with a lot of errors. any improvements on my code? thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public user getLOGusr(String uname, String pass)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    // replace * with comma-separated column names
    // if you do not wish to return all columns
    String select = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USRS + " WHERE " + KEY_NAME + " = ? AND " + KEY_PASS + " = ?";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(select, new String[]{uname, pass});

    // get the data from the Cursor and return stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String[] tableColumns = new String[] {
  KEY_ID,KEY_NAME,KEY_E_ADDR,KEY_PASS
};
String whereClause = KEY_NAME + " = ? AND " + KEY_PASS  + " = ?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {
  uname,
  pass
};
Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_USRS, tableColumns, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null);
```

Comment: What is the point of calling `String.valueOf()` when the params are both `String`s?